# Add scss file to the Stackblitz

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

Can you tell me how to add `scss` file to the `stackblitz`. I tried that.But it is not working. Please see that and let me know.

I have tried to add `home.html`

*This is the project:* [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a6vpji)

Comment: Where exactly do you add it?

Comment: Hope you can see that using above link no? I tried to `home` folder. @voloshin

Comment: I opened all the folders except this one. :) Now I see a `.scss` file. Maybe it sounds a bit weird but do you know that you should compile `scss` to `css` to include it to a page? Because I can't see a scss-complier in your project.

Comment: How can I do that? I just started to use `stckblitz`. @voloshin

Comment: Okay, now we know the problem. I'm going to create an answer, wait a few minutes.

Comment: OK sure. Thanks in advance :) @voloshin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Scss should work in stackblitz**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.scss' ] <== add this
})
export class HomePage {
```

Styles like

```
 page-home {
 .buttoncls {
```

won't work for you with default encapsulation(`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`) because `page-home` is not part of `home` component template and angular adds attribute like `[_ngcontent-c0]` to styles.

So we can change `page-home` to `ion-list` and see how it works:

**[Stackblitz Example (ViewEncapsulation.Emulated)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rveccu?file=pages/home/home.scss)**

But we can disable encapsulation:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

**[Stackblitz Example (ViewEncapsulation.None)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kzs5wj?file=pages/home/home.scss)**

See also this thread

https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/1

As EricSimons commented 9 days ago:

> Hey all! We just shipped SASS and LESS support, and we also support
>   the angular-cli.json config too :)

Comment: Simply amazing. Thank you so much. Hope `stackblitz` rocks the `StackOverflow` and `Ionic` world :)

Answer (score 2):

Above answer does not work anymore.
Update:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'home.scss' ] <== add this
})
```

Also - the styles must go in the most outside block and shouldn't go under other block.

Comment: Please tell me what exactly doesn't work in the answer above?