# CSS values not applying on dynamically injected html div elements in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/deepakpookkote/pen/xXRNao)

I have an Angular calendar application that is running fine. without any errors. But the problem I'm facing here is the CSS styles are not getting applied to the page.

I implemented this separately and its working fine. But when I include it in my angular css is not working. (The problem I'm facing here is I don't know to how to refer the 'div' that contain the contents).

I'm sharing my code below:

holidays.ts

```
@Component({
  //template: ``,
  templateUrl: './holidays.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../../../webroot/css/pages/holidays/only_holidays.min.css'],
  styles: [`



  `],
})
export class HolidaysPageComponent extends AppComponent {


  ngOnInit(){
    this.testFunction();
  }


  testFunction() {

    $(function() {
      function c() {
          p();
          var e = h();
          var r = 0;
          var u = false;
          l.empty();
          while (!u) {
              if (s[r] == e[0].weekday) {
                  u = true
              } else {
                  l.append('<div class="blank"></div>');
                  r++
              }
          }
          for (var c = 0; c < 42 - r; c++) {
              if (c >= e.length) {
                  l.append('<div class="blank"></div>')
              } else {
                  var v = e[c].day;
                  var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v)) ? '<div class="today">' : "<div>";
                  l.append(m + "" + v +"<div class='eventsPrint e-day-"+v+"'></div></div>");

              }
          }
          var y = o[n - 1];
          a.css("background-color", y).find("h1").text(i[n - 1] + " " + t);
          f.find("div").css("color", y);
          l.find(".today").css("background-color", y);
          d()
      }

      function h() {
          var e = [];
          for (var r = 1; r < v(t, n) + 1; r++) {
              e.push({
                  day: r,
                  weekday: s[m(t, n, r)]
              })
          }
          return e
      }

      function p() {
          f.empty();
          for (var e = 0; e < 7; e++) {
              f.append("<div>" + s[e].substring(0, 3) + "</div>")
          }
      }

      function d() {
          var t;
          var n = $("#calendar").css("width", e + "px");
          n.find(t = "#calendar_weekdays, #calendar_content").css("width", e + "px").find("div").css({
              width: e / 7 + "px",
              height: e / 7 + "px",
              "line-height": e / 7 + "px"
          });
          n.find("#calendar_header").css({
              height: e * (1 / 7) + "px"
          }).find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').css("line-height", e * (1 / 7) + "px")
      }

      function v(e, t) {
          return (new Date(e, t, 0)).getDate()
      }

      function m(e, t, n) {
          return (new Date(e, t - 1, n)).getDay()
      }

      function g(e) {
          return y(new Date) == y(e)
      }

      function y(e) {
          return e.getFullYear() + "/" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + e.getDate()
      }

      function b() {
          var e = new Date;
          t = e.getFullYear();
          n = e.getMonth() + 1
      }

      var e = 480;
      var t = 2013;
      var n = 9;
      var r = [];
      var i = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
      var s = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
      var o = ["#16a085", "#1abc9c", "#c0392b", "#27ae60", "#FF6860", "#f39c12", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#2ecc71", "#e74c3c", "#d35400", "#2c3e50"];
      var u = $("#calendar");
      var a = u.find("#calendar_header");
 // console.log(a[0]);
 ///=============================================================================================================================

    eventUpdater();

  //==============================================================================================================================
    var f = u.find("#calendar_weekdays");
    var l = u.find("#calendar_content");
    b();
    c();
    a.find('i[class^="icon-chevron"]').on("click", function() {
        var e = $(this);
        var r = function(e) {
            n = e == "next" ? n + 1 : n - 1;
            if (n < 1) {
                n = 12;
                t--
            } else if (n > 12) {
                n = 1;
                t++
            }
            c()
        };
        if (e.attr("class").indexOf("left") != -1) {
            r("previous")
        } else {
            r("next")
        }
        ///=============================================================================================================================

    eventUpdater();

  //==============================================================================================================================
    })
  })

  function eventUpdater(){
    let iM = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      let cald=$('#calendar_header h1').html();
      cald=cald.split(" ");
      let MM=cald[0]; let YY=cald[1];
      let curMonth=iM.indexOf(MM);
      if(curMonth){
      console.log( $('#calendar_header h1' ).html() , iM.indexOf(MM) ,YY  );
        $(".eventsPrint").html(''); //clearing all event display
        if(curMonth==8 && YY==2017){
          $(".e-day-26").html("<ul><li>Event 1</li><li>Event 2</li></ul>")
        }

      }
    } );
  }
  }

}
```

only_holidays.css

```
body{
  background-color: #F5F1E9;
}
#calendar{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 520px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#calendar_weekdays div{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#calendar_content, #calendar_weekdays, #calendar_header{
  position: relative;
  width: 520px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}
#calendar_weekdays div, #calendar_content div{
  width:50px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #787878;
}
#calendar_content{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
}
#calendar_content div{
  float: left;
}
#calendar_content div:hover{
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
#calendar_content div.blank{
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
#calendar_header, #calendar_content div.today{
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#calendar_content div.today{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#calendar_header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF6860;
  padding: 18px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
}
#calendar_header h1{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float:left;
  width:70%;
}
```

which ever styles that refers to (div) is not working//..

https://codepen.io/deepakpookkote/pen/xXRNao

Comment: Can you provide plunker or stackblitz example that will show us the issue?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU?p=info ..this is the plunker of my code @yurzui

Comment: Sorry but is don't see calendar there

Comment: https://codepen.io/deepakpookkote/pen/xXRNao : -can you plz check this link and tell please tell me how to do this in angular ..when i do it alone its working ..but  in angular css is not working fine @yurzui ..

Comment: Please take a look https://plnkr.co/edit/mCldcxqZom8L4OSSiUyz?p=preview

Comment: its working when i add css into style.css but why its not working as internal css or in other external names ? @yurzui

Comment: Do you add it to styleUrls?

Comment: yes i did and its working fine now..but still i have one doubt .if i add that into style.css (style urls) it will be applicable globally ryt .. and thanks for your time being help..@yurzui

Comment: Reproduce it in my example

Comment: like i told you .there is one default file(style.css) .its working only in that file  ..https://plnkr.co/edit/ovJ8N2TC1vunvxUP8zfZ?p=preview

Comment: and i tried the solution given below by  @LLai :- import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './holidays.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./../../../webroot/css/pages/holidays/only_holidays.min.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
}) : this one is perfect ..have a look at this

Comment: Angular adds prefix to css classes in emulated mode. Just check how your styles look like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252546/add-scss-file-to-the-stackblitz/46252914#46252914

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I believe this is a css encapsulation issue. By default angular uses the `Emulated` encapsulation. This applies an attribute to all the DOM elements in your component and adds that attribute to your css rules. Since you are injecting html dynamically and not through angular, that attribute it not being added to your dynamic html. You can use the `None` option. This way angular doesn't add the attribute to your css rules.

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './holidays.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./../../../webroot/css/pages/holidays/only_holidays.min.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Note, now your css won't be encapsulated for just this component. It'll be available to your entire app.

Docs on ViewEncapsulation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Here is a good article on ViewEncapsulation (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)