# Fullcalendar Angular - Tooltip.js CSS is not applied (CSS encapsulation issue)

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, tooltip, fullcalendar-4

I've added Tooltip.js on Fullcalendar's events for eventMouseEnter and eventMouseLeave, but the Tooltip is not styled, it shows just a plain text. See the image below.

[image]
I have tried to use [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo) example here, but with no results.

How can I style the Tooltip like the following example?

[image]

This is my code:

**appointment.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGrigPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import roLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/ro';
import Tooltip from 'tooltip.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment',
  templateUrl: './appointment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment.component.css']
})

export class AppointmentComponent {
  tooltip: Tooltip;

  @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the template
  calendarLocale = roLocale;
  calendarVisible = true;
  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
  calendarWeekends = true;
  calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [
    { title: 'Cod: #123124124', description: "TEXT", start: new Date(), customRender: true },
  ];

  handleEventMouseEnter(info) {
    this.tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: info.event.title,
      placement: 'top'
    });
  }
  handleEventMouseLeave(info) {
    this.tooltip.dispose();
  }
}
```

**appointment.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth"
    [header]="{left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'}"
    [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [weekends]="calendarWeekends" [events]="calendarEvents" [locale]="calendarLocale"
    (eventMouseEnter)="handleEventMouseEnter($event)"
    (eventMouseLeave)="handleEventMouseLeave($event)"></full-calendar>
```

**LE**: it seems the CSS is not applying. I've used the CSS from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a CSS encapsulation issue. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406274/7972851) answer.

Adding

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment',
  templateUrl: './appointment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the *title* element is `textElement` and doesn't have extra styling. If you want to style the tooltip, then you have to enable the use of *HTML* in the *options* parameter of the constructor.

```
  handleEventMouseEnter(info) {
    this.tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      html: true,
      title: "<b>" + info.event.title + "</b>",
      placement: 'top'
    });
  }
```

This code above should make the tooltip **text bold**.
Or, **you could wrap the title HTML styling as you want.**

Comment: This is working, but it's not the result I wanted. Check the picture above to see an example. The problem is, I think, that the CSS is not applying.

Comment: I managed to find a solution. It was a CSS encapsulation issue.