# NextJS: dynamically created html nodes not repainted by css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I was working on a nextjs project where I was asked to add an external script that dynamically creates nodes using vanilla js (createElement, setAttribute, etc.). I couldn't help but notice that the global css imported at the top of my _app.js did not affect these dynamically created elements at all. I tried importing the css many different ways but couldn't get the nodes to be repainted without modifying the external script and dynamically adding the styling there.

Does anyone know why exactly these nodes aren't repainted by the imported css and how to import them / configure next in a way where they are ?

Thank you !

P.S: script works and is imported in , tried importing css in  too without luck

Comment: Hi, I recommend you to add part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question where the answer was an issue with css encapsulation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403698/css-values-not-applying-on-dynamically-injected-html-div-elements-in-angular-4) is the link to that answer, it explains it better than I can. Their issue was with angular so it could be the same.