# How to set a large Dynamic table data responsive using ion-col

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

here im facing a issue related      ion-col  , i am binding my dynamic data to the ion - row and display data in the ion-col here the table is huge and it is cutting off and widths of that unstable below is my cod

```
<ion-grid class="contnr">
      <ion-row style="" class="grid-head">
        <ion-col width-40>
          Transaction
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          Count
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40 >
         Overall  Gross Amount
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40 >
          Overall Disc
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  width-40>
          Overall Tax
        </ion-col >
        <ion-col  width-40>
         Overall ServiceTax
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  width-40>
         Overall Charge
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  width-40>
          Overall Net
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let value of resultData" style="background:#eff0f1" class="cont-rows">

        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.TransacType}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.Transactions}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.Count}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.OverallSales}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.Discount}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.OverallTax}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.MandatoryTax}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.ServiceCharge}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-40>
          {{value.NetAmt}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          Total
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
          {{grossTotal}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{Nets}}
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

here the problem  the table is so long that it is cutting  off and even though im setting of using scss but the col and col data is not getting in properly aligning

[image: Table Data]

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or a plunker ?

Comment: Can you simulate it here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Sampath  check this url https://ionic-whawjk.stackblitz.io/ in this way im getting & really thanx for  url related to stackblitz

Comment: You need to share the page's url.

Comment: @Sampath https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-whawjk

Comment: No data no? `resultData`?

Comment: @Sampath  Actually it is a Dynamic Json data which im getting and if u see the fields u can see how the field name is cutting off

Comment: Which field did you mean?

Comment: If you need to show `scss` on  `stackblitz` you can see how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252546/add-scss-file-to-the-stackblitz

Comment: @Sampath Table Headers

Comment: Can you show the image where how you need those headers?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? If not can you show an image of your exact requirement?

Comment: @Sampath actually i posted an image to u and by using the scss i made some modifications and i updated my question with image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do it using [**Responsive attributes**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#all-breakpoints).

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rpzdrg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

> To customize a column's width for all devices and screens, add the
>   col-* attribute. These attributes tell the column to take up * columns
>   out of the available columns.

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4>
      1 of 4
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2>
      2 of 4
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2>
      3 of 4
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>
      4 of 4
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You can `show/hide` columns according to the [**screen breakpoints**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#default-breakpoints) too.

**Note:** Here it `hides` all the columns on `md` breakpoint.

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rii3yt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

*.scss*

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6 class="hidden-md">
                1 of 4
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6 class="hidden-md">
                2 of 4
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: i have so many fields so based on screen resolution is it possible to define the fields to show and hide?

Comment: i  got solutions  for the resolution i used hideWhen & showWhen properties

Comment: Ok, Great... :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a UX issue rather than a development issue.

Second, a table should be a table, not a grid !! Your HTML code should be semantic.

I had this issue before on some app I was working on, and here what I did (might not be the best solution for all situations) depending on your demands, and the priority for data to be visualized next to other data (for example compare last month profits with current month).

[image]

**SASS:**

```
ion-grid
{
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

ion-row
{
    display: table;       
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Make sure these styles are only applied on the desired page, so use css specifier, or replace tags with IDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the  grid columns and their padding can be modified via Sass variables.

`$grid-columns` is a ionic-sass variable mainly used to generate the widths (in percent) for the  each individual column.

`$grid-padding-width` is another variable used for the padding on the grid, while this also allows you to set the breakpoint-specific widths that are divided evenly across padding-left and padding-right as well as padding-top and padding-bottom of the grid and columns.

Generally you can set the different breakpoints based on the devices. like as follows:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  sm: 0,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);
```

for that break points you can set the max-width as follows :

```
$grid-max-widths: (
  sm: 420px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px
);
```

For implementing more about responsive grid in Ionic [check this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid)